# getting Titlebar state of MDIsubwindow in drawComplexControl

Tags: python, pyqt5

i am trying to get the state of MDIsubwindow TitleBar in drawComplexControl
according to source code
bool active = (option->titleBarState & QStyle::State_Active);
but this is not working
here is minimal reproducible example

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QProxyStyle, QStyle, QStyleOptionTitleBar


class MyProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):

    def drawComplexControl(self, control: QStyle.ComplexControl, option: QStyleOptionTitleBar,
                       painter: QtGui.QPainter, widget=None) -> None:
    if option.titleBarState == QProxyStyle.State_Active:
        print("active")
    super().drawComplexControl(control, option, painter, widget)


class Mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mywindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Customized style")
        self.mdiarea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdiarea)
        self.mdiarea.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.window.setMinimumSize(160, 120)
        self.window2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.window2.setMinimumSize(320, 220)

        sw1 = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()
        sw1.setWindowTitle("Test")
        sw1.setWidget(self.window)
        sw2 = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()
        sw2.setWindowTitle("Test2")
        sw2.setWidget(self.window2)
        self.mdiarea.addSubWindow(sw1)
        self.mdiarea.addSubWindow(sw2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    my_style = MyProxyStyle("fusion")
    app.setStyle(my_style)
    view = Mywindow()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Typo: use `&` just like in the sources, not `==`. Please do some research about binary operators.

Comment: i have checked bitwise operator thanks a lot